# Dragging custom view in scroll area

Tags: android, touch-event, android-custom-view

So I have a custom view widget I am allowing a user to drag around by their finger. They are dragging it in a custom scrolling view based on a FrameLayout (code here: http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/) that contains a RelativeLayout, so that they can place it where they want and have plenty of space that is not visible on screen to place the item as well.

What I would like to happen is if the user is moving the widget near the edge of the visible scroll area is to scroll the area in the appropriate direction until they either let go (ACTION_UP, in which case no more events would take place anyway) or have moved away from the edge. The code right now has two problems:

1) My phone (T-Mobile G2) continues to trigger ACTION_MOVE even when my finger is still where as my Nexus 7 tablet does not continue to trigger until it has moved. I need to reliably continue to trigger this event until ACTION_UP.

2) The area scrolls but only as I move my finger towards the edge of the screen. In otherwords, I'd like for a finger that is staying still to continue to scroll and move the object when it is near the edge, but this is not happening.

What am I missing? Here is the onTouchEvent that handles the moving of the widget

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
            && this.getParent() != null) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    // mScrollParent gets set in a setter and points to the TwoDScrollView
    // mOffsetX/Y is based on where the user touches versus the position of the custom view
    // mWidth/mHeight gets set once in the GestureDetector based on the custom view's getWidth()/getHeight()
    // mTitleBarHeight gets set once in the GestureDetctor onDown event
    // lp is a ViewGroup.LayoutParams type
    if (!mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            int finalX = (int) (event.getRawX() - mOffsetX);
            int finalY = (int) (event.getRawY() - mOffsetY - (mTitleBarHeight > 0 ? mTitleBarHeight * 2
                    : 0));

            if (finalX < 0 || finalY < 0)
                return false;

            int scrollLeft = (int) Math.ceil(mScrollParent.getScrollX() * 1.05);
            int scrollTop = (int) Math.ceil(mScrollParent.getScrollY() * 1.05);
            int scrollRight = (int) Math.floor((scrollLeft + mScrollParent.getRight()) * 0.95);
            int scrollBottom = (int) Math.floor((scrollTop + mScrollParent.getBottom()) * 0.95);
            int scrollX = 0;
            int scrollY = 0;

            if (scrollLeft > finalX)
                scrollX = finalX - scrollLeft;

            if (scrollRight < (finalX + mWidth))
                scrollX = (finalX + mWidth)- scrollRight;

            if (scrollTop > finalY)
                scrollY = finalY - scrollTop;

            if (scrollBottom < (finalY + mHeight))
                scrollY = (finalY + mHeight) - scrollBottom;

            if (scrollX != 0 || scrollY != 0)
                mScrollParent.scrollBy(scrollX * 4, scrollY * 4);

            lp.setMargins(finalX + scrollX, finalY + scrollY, 0, 0);
            setLayoutParams(lp);

            return true;
        }
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```